# What am I doing wrong with my Fixed LOD expression?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I created a calculated field using Fixed LOD to get the distinct values of a field called Estimated ARR because there are duplicates due to joining two tables (with SQL).

The calculation, Distinct Estimated ARR, is:

```
{FIXED [Estimated ARR] : AVG([Estimated ARR]) }
```

And when I sum the values in the view, it only has the correct values for 2 of the 4 rows. I'm not sure why this is happening.

This is showing what the ARR values should be for each Customer Segment (using the data before the join):
[image: correct ARR]

This shows the sum of the estimated ARR (not distinct due to duplicates in joined dataset) with the sum of the distinct estimated ARR, which come from my LOD expression. As you can see, Customer Segments A and C are showing values that are off by a few hundred thousand, while B and D have accurate sums.
[image]

Please let me know if any other info is needed. I was trying to keep this as short as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer here for anyone who is curious! https://community.tableau.com/s/feed/0D58b0000A9ZJhoCQG?t=1664819504200